# Converting Java 8 Syntax to Anonymous Inner Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

How can I convert uriBuilder Lambda function into an anonymous inner class?

```
webclient.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/api/person/{personId}")
    .queryParam("param1", aDouble)
    .queryParam("param2", "A string value with spaces")
    .queryParam("param3", aListOfValues)
    .queryParam("param4", null)
    .build(anInteger))
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert the lambda into anonymous inner class?

Comment: I am seeing SAST scan issues & wanted to check if I am seeing false positives only when I use lambda functions.

Comment: Check the parameter type of `uri` method and just create an anonymous inner class

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Now read: [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: The signature of `uri` method is something like this `S uri(Function<UriBuilder,URI> uriFunction)`. So just create an anonymous inner class of Function class and pass that to `uri` method.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you're using IntelliJ, you can move your cursor to `uriBuilder` and press Alt+Enter and apply  'Replace lambda with anonymous class' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `webclient` is a [`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html), then the method is [`uri(Function<UriBuilder,URI> uriFunction)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html#uri-java.util.function.Function-), which means you need an anonymous class implementing functional interface [`Function<UriBuilder,URI>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html?is-external=true):

```java
new Function<UriBuilder,URI>() {
    @Override
    public URI apply(UriBuilder uriBuilder) {
        return uriBuilder.path("/api/person/{personId}")
                .queryParam("param1", aDouble)
                .queryParam("param2", "A string value with spaces")
                .queryParam("param3", aListOfValues)
                .queryParam("param4", null)
                .build(anInteger);
    }
}
```